# Access Variable that is in code space in Assembler

Tags: 8051, keil, c51

[Keil's C51](http://www.keil.com/c51/) allows the use of sharing [global variables between C and Assembler code](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_ap_globalvars.htm). However I need to store a variable in the code space of an 8051 microcontroller. Yet when I try to access the variable in assembler I get some errors.

I have the following declaration in my c source file:

```
unsigned char code STATE = 0xFF;
```

And in my header file it looks like:

```
extern unsigned char code STATE;
```

With the Keils C51 compiler it is possible to access global variables in C using the [EXTERN keyword](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/a51/a51_st_extern.htm) in your assembly code so in my assembly I have:

```
EXTERN CODE (STATE)
```

However when I try to access the variable in my assembly I get the error: [DATA-ADDRESS EXPECTED](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/a51/a51_a48.htm):

```
 MOV     A, STATE ; Move state to A;
```

Also as it is in the code space it should access using a MOVC instruction so this should work:

```
 MOVC     A, STATE ; Move state to A;
```

Yet this yields an EXPRESSION TYPE DOES NOT MATCH INSTRUCTION error([AX51 error A22](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/a51/a51_a22.htm)).

So how can I access this variable in assembler?

Comment: Err....  what assembler?  What C compiler?  ... just generally ... what?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about C and Assembly programming, not electronic design.

Comment: @Majenko Added some more information about the question. Yes it is about programming but for microcontrollers which is on-topic here. Also if this question was answered on Stack overflow I wouldn't get the answer because of the use of an industrial compiler for the 8051 architecture.

Comment: Have you read this? http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/a51/a51_wp_code.htm

Comment: Unless the code space of this microcontroller is implemented as RAM, you can't have a *variable* there.

Comment: @Majenko Cheers didn't notice that link before. Following that seems to fix the errors!

Comment: I'll craft it as an answer then so the question can be put to bed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only access the CODE section via the DPTR register.  From the [AX51 manual](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/a51/a51_wp_code.htm):

> CODE memory can be accessed with the instruction MOVC via the DPTR register.
>
> Example for all 8051 variants:

```
?CO?my_seg SEGMENT CODE                ; define a SEGMENT of class CODE
       RSEG    ?CO?my_seg
TABLE:     DB      1,2,4,8,0x10        ; a table with constant values

?PR?myprog SEGMENT CODE                ; define a segment for program code
       RSEG    ?PR?myprog
       MOV     DPTR,#TABLE         ; load address of table
       MOV     A,#3                ; load offset into table
       MOVC    A,@A+DPTR           ; access via MOVC instruction
```

So it would be a case of loading the DPTR register with the *address* of your external variable and using an offset of 0:

```
MOV     DPTR, #STATE
MOV     A, #0
```

then accessing that address using DPTR:

```
MOVC    A,@A+DPTR
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, a variable in the code space is not a variable but a constant! The syntax hints towards that as you use the accumulator as an offset for the address in the data pointer register.